# error:0A00010B:SSL while trying to connect local websocket server

Tags: scala, websocket, postman, tls1.3, http4s

I run a very basic websocket server. Just a copy-paste from
https://http4s.org/v1/docs/service.html#running-your-service-as-an-app

I tried to connect with the websocket server using Postman, curl, wscat... but everything give the same result. I will post the results from `wscat`:

```
wscat -c "wss://localhost:8080/hello/name"
error: write EPROTO C0F7A4FA377F0000:error:0A00010B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:355:


wscat -c "ws://localhost:8080/hello/name"
error: Unexpected server response: 200
```

Later I put also `withoutTls` for `EmberServerBuilder`, but it changes nothing.

I run everything on Pop!_OS (ubuntu like).

`openssl s_client -connect host.com:443 -tls1_3` shows that OS runs tls 1.3.
I don't know where to search. OS config? Websocket server config? Websocket client (postman, wscat) config?

Comment: What code are you using to expose the WS endpoint?

Comment: @GaëlJ I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but code of websocket server is in the link at the beginning of my post - official http4s site.

Comment: Isn't the issue that you are using websocket tools to connect to an endpoint which returns a response and closes connection? For websocket you should have some streaming solution: https://http4s.org/v1/docs/streaming.html#streaming-responses-from-your-service while the example from the docs you posted is a "normal" endpoint .

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok yes, of course!! I done the same mistake in my code which I was working on.  Then I fond the example above and totally missed the fact that it is standard http endpoint. Thank you a lot!